# Reading file and adding into 2 dimensional double array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read a file full of coordinates and then putting everything into double 2 dimensional array. When i run the code I get the exception error. Been trying to read the file for hours now (I'm a noobie in java)

```
try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            int row=0;
            int col=0;
            int rwn=0;
            String[] line= new String[rwn];
            while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                line = input.nextLine().split(" ");//spliting 1
                rwn++;
            }
            double[][] arrayOfEarth = new double[rwn][];  // creating array for pairs
            // iterating array ^ of splitting 1
            for (int i = 0; i < rwn; i++) {
                String[] ln =line[i].split(",");

                double a= Double.parseDouble(ln[0]);
                double b=Double.parseDouble(ln[1]);
                double[] val={a,b};  // adding the a and b doubles out of string  to the value
                arrayOfEarth[i]=val;  // add arr to arr of arr
            }

            for (double[] c:arrayOfEarth) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%.0f and %.2f",c[0],c[1]));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error bruh: "); e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us the contents of the file, please?

Comment: @Schred  so the file contains 2milion+ rows and 3 collumns.                                                                                   ```   
0 90 -4228
0.166666666667 90 -4228
0.333333333333 90 -4228
0.5 90 -4228
0.666666666667 90 -4228
0.833333333333 90 -4228
1 90 -4228
1.16666666667 90 -4228
1.33333333333 90 -4228
1.5 90 -4228
1.66666666667 90 -4228
1.83333333333 90 -4228
2 90 -4228
2.16666666667 90 -4228
2.33333333333 90 -4228
2.5 90 -4228
2.66666666667 90 -4228
2.83333333333 90 -4228
3 90 -4228
3.16666666667 90 -4228
3.33333333333 90 -4228
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code confused me a bit.

But you can try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define sample data
        String coord = ""
                + "0 90 -4228\n"
                + "0.166666666667 90 -4228\n"
                + "0.333333333333 90 -4228\n"
                + "0.5 90 -4228\n"
                + "0.666666666667 90 -4228";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(coord);
        int rwn = 0;
        // Define a 'arrayOfEarth' as list
        ArrayList<Double[]> arrayOfEarth = new ArrayList<>();
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            ++rwn;
            String[] line = input.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (line.length == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            arrayOfEarth.add(parseLine(line, rwn));
        }
        arrayOfEarth.stream()
                .forEach(v -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v) + "\n"));

    }

    private static Double[] parseLine(String[] line, int row) {
        if (line.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing valiues in line " + row);
        }
        Double[] doubles = new Double[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                doubles[i] = Double.parseDouble(line[i]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new NumberFormatException("NAN in " + row + "/" + i + ". value: " + line[i]);
            }
        }
        return doubles;
    }
}
```

This is not 'clean' code - only an example. 
I have used the Stream-API. If you use a Java Version < 8 you have to rewrite it with a traditional for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

````
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        int row=0;
        int col=0;
        int rwn=0;
        //String[] line= new String[rwn]; you created line with zero length;
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine().split(" ");//spliting 1
            rwn++;
        }

        String[] line= new String[rwn];
        double[][] arrayOfEarth = new double[rwn][];  // creating array for pairs

        // iterating array ^ of splitting 1
        for (int i=0;i<rwn;i++){
            String[] ln =line[i].split(",");

            double a= Double.parseDouble(ln[0]);
            double b=Double.parseDouble(ln[1]);
            double[] val={a,b};//adding the a and b doubles out of string  to the value
            arrayOfEarth[i]=val;//add arr to arr of arr
        }
        for (double[] c:arrayOfEarth){
            System.out.println(String.format("%.0f and %.2f",c[0],c[1]));
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error bruh: "); e.printStackTrace();
    }```
````

String[] line= new String[rwn]; has to be under while statement. you created line with 0 length